# How to make rsync copy to symlinks?

Tags: linux, rsync, symbolic-link, scp

I have to push data from a server to another.

On the source, I have a folder (named `vhosts`) containing files, folders and symlinks. I want all this to be copied as files (not as symlinks)

On the destination, I have a folder (named `vhosts`) to receive all files. This folder contains one folder that is a symlink to another volume because the data it will receive is too big for that disk. That is why a folder was created as a symlink to another volume.

I ran a couple of commands with different parameters. The last I got was this:

```
rsync -rLzP vhosts/ user@10.0.0.23:/home/user/vhosts/
```

The problem is that this deleted my symbolic link on the destination folder and created a directory. The data is not copied to the second volume so I won't be able to complete the task. I thought `-L` would solve it but it has not the impact I was expecting.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need `--keep-dirlinks`

> --keep-dirlinks         treat symlinked dir on receiver as dir